# What measures were taken by the Bolsheviks to consolidate their position?

Tags: communism, russian-civil-war

What are four measures taken by the Bolsheviks before December of 1917 to suppress threats to their position?

I know that:

1)They promised elections to the assembly to be held in November 1917.

2) They gave the peasants land. They nationalized all the land, granting it to rural soviets to distribute it out to the peasants.

I cannot think of anything else... please even correct me if the two measures are wrong.

Comment: This looks terribly like homework. If it is, the answers will be in your set reading.

Comment: The main trigger of the revolution was... (hint: which year did it happen)?

Comment: Try to edit the question  to something as: what measures allowed the relatively weak bolshevik's party, without majority in any state constitutional or revolutional body or in military forces, not only take, but retain the power?

Comment: And please, remove your version of the decree on Land. It is pure nonsense. There were few soviets on the village level in 1917. The county soviets had to observe only. The old good village commune had to do the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is obviously out of a study book. And not a good one.

1. After October revolution there were 3 parties at power: bolsheviks, left SRs and maximalists(a branch of anarchists). It was named Soviet Power, not bolshevik's one. And the name was correct in 1917 and half of 1918.
2. There were not 4 measures, Soviet Power took thousands of measures to keep the power. Its position in 1917-1918 was very weak. And the choice of most useful measures is subjective enough.

Soviet Power made two main laws:
**Peace**. They stopped to fight non only separately from allies, but even before any agreements with enemy.
**Land**. They took the well-known and thoroughly made project of SR party and made it a law.

It also started preparations to the elections of Uchreditelnoje (Constitutional) Congress.

I would name as a fourth measure of bolsheviks the temporary three-party system. They could not destroy the Peasants' Soviet in October, as they destroyed the Constitutional Congress later in January. Army was not yet on they side. So, they badly needed left SRs at their side. And in the Workers and Soldiers' Soviets they needed anarchists for the same reason. And without the majority in these both Soviets they would instantly lose. Without support of other parties they had majority in the city Soviet **only**.

That power was officially supported by a Decree on Establishment of the Workers' and Peasants' Government, but we can't count it as one of the main measures - it only wrote down the real fact.

If you don't like my choice, look at the list of their laws and choose yourself:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_Decree

I think, Decree on the Nationalization of the Banks and Decree on the State Independence of Finland were very important.

As for non-decree measures, IMHO, the arrest of the previous government, **official move of the power to Soviets** and very careful politics towards neutral troops were extremely important, too, no less than the first 4 measures.